# Why counter defined with useRef hook is not incrementing on each render?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am trying use the hook useRef() to keep a counter of which items to display next, and increment the counter on each render and using the counter value to slice in elements in an array. On each render the counter index.current should increase by 10 but in my case its not increasing and I keep getting the same 10 elements over and over. I can't figure out why. The collection overview component here is mapping over the collection preview component 4 times.

```
//CollectionPreview

const CollectionPreview = ({title,movieItems,Counter}) =>  {
     const index = React.useRef(0)
     const movieData = movieItems.slice(index.current, index.current + 10)
     index.current += 10

        return (
            <div className="collection-preview">
                <h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
                  <div className="preview"> 
                    {console.log(movieData)}
                  </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    movieItems: selectMovieItems(state),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CollectionPreview);


//CollectionOverview

class CollectionOverview extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <div className="collection-overview">
            {
                CollectionData.map(items => 
                    <CollectionPreview key={items.id} title={items.title} />)
            }
        </div>

    );
}
}

export default CollectionOverview;
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you expect every `CollectionPreview` in your `CollectionOverview` to display a different page?

Comment: No CollectionOverview is the page and each CollectionPreview is a movie grid, just like netflix. Here though there are only four grids as CollectionOverview maps over CollectionPreview four times.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think counting the number of renders is bad pattern, as renders can be called multiple times in different occasions and its difficult to keep track of every single render call as your app gets bigger.

I think a better approach is to have a `initialIndex` or `pageIndex` in some state somewhere. As you are using Redux, I think you should put that in the reducer and create the appropriate actions to increment this value.